# How can I print a byte string of an integer to a socket in Java?

Tags: java, android, sockets, type-conversion, printwriter

Using Java 8 for Android development.

How can I print an integer in base256 to a socket?  This code I've been trying for some reason prints 5 bytes...

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
int FileSize = 430200;
byte[] BytFileSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(FileSize).array();
String StrFileSize = new String(BytFileSize, "ISO-8859-1");
out.print(StrFileSize);
out.flush();
```

---

It prints:

```
"00 06 c2 90 78"
```

The expected is:

```
"00 06 90 78"
```

Weird that it puts a "c2" in between the two 16-bit pieces...

Comment: 'Print' and 'base 256' are mutually contradictory. What makes you think that a base-256 quantity can be represented as a String? Why are you doing all this convolution when `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` already exists?

Comment: Basically because I didn't know that DataOutputStream existed. Most of my programming experience is in C++, and I'm just learning Java to port my client to Android. In C++, the std::string type can hold base 256 data without a problem, as it is basically a (8-bit)char[] wrapped in class... Java's default string type is (frustratingly) a (16-bit)char[], and uses unicode by default... Reason I'd like to use string as opposed to byte[] is that I prefer writing OOP when possible, and I have string data to send as well. I guess maybe i'll just write a stdstring class that will better suit my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617245/is-there-a-string-type-in-java-based-on-on-an-8-bit-byte-array I wrote a little class here but would appreciate any simpler solutions! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
int FileSize = 430200;
byte[] BytFileSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(FileSize).array();
out.write(BytFileSize);
out.flush();
```

But I'm not sure why the PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream))).print(String) version doesn't work correctly.