# Is there a string type in Java based on on an 8-bit byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, byte

Is there any string type/class in Java (standard or otherwise) that is based on an array of the 8-bit byte type, and not the 16-bit char type?

I really like the std::string type in C++, as it works very well with parsing base256 (binary) data...

I went ahead and wrote a little class that provides most of the features I need (below), but a better one would be appreciated!

```
public class stdstring extends Object {
    private byte [] bytedata;

    public stdstring() {
        bytedata = new byte[0];
    }

    public stdstring(byte[] bytes) {
        bytedata = bytes;
    }

    public stdstring(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
        bytedata = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes,offset,bytedata,0,length);
    }

    public stdstring(String string) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        bytedata = new byte[string.length()];
        bytedata = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    }

    public void assign(byte[] bytes) {
        bytedata = new byte[bytes.length];
        bytedata = bytes;
    }

    public void assign(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
        bytedata = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes,offset,bytedata,0,length);
    }

    public void assign(String string) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        bytedata = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    }

    public int length() {
        return bytedata.length;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        byte [] copy = new byte[bytedata.length];
        System.arraycopy(bytedata,0,copy,0,bytedata.length);
        return copy;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(int offset, int length) {
        byte [] piece = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(bytedata,offset,piece,0,length);
        return piece;
    }

    public byte getByte(int offset) {
        byte b = bytedata[offset];
        return b;
    }

    public stdstring substring(int offset, int length) {
        stdstring sub = new stdstring(bytedata, offset, length);
        return sub;
    }

    public boolean equals(stdstring string) {
        if (bytedata.length != string.length()) { return false; }
        for (int i = 0; i < bytedata.length; ++i) {
            if (bytedata[i] != string.getByte(i)) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about why the difference matters to you?

Comment: Also, see http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254

Comment: Because when I'm sending data and text through a socket, it's easiest to know that 1 byte is either 1 byte of data or one text character... the only reason i need to send text is for filenames and server commands, I dont need a million unicode characters for that.  plus, just that C++, the language my server app is written in, uses (mostly) 8-bit strings.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you're sending text between any two apps -- whether they're written in the same language or not -- you should just specify an encoding and use that encoding to convert, usually UTF-8 (which will also be efficient on ASCII characters).  You can convert between Java Strings and UTF-8 bytes with `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: ... or you can use `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` if you want 8-bit ness.

Comment: I guess that would work, but I already have a server/client pair written in C++, and I'm not trying to have to do it in a radically different way, especially not have to modify the server...  This is just a port to Java for an Android version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code review.stackexchange.com... It's half way between a code self-recommendation and a request for a code review.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd vote to close as too broad. "Belongs on Code Review" really isn't a valid close reason. Maybe vote to close as "too broad"?

Comment: [Just because a question is said to have "working code" and seems to be on-topic on Code Review, doesn't mean that it is automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/52915)

Comment: @Mast: I agree with that in general, but I still think it's off-topic here (possibly as too broad, I agree with Ethan) but would expect it to be reasonalby on topic on codereview.